# Выделение памяти через шаблон

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Auto_ptr1
{
    T* m_ptr;
public:

    Auto_ptr1(T* ptr = nullptr)
        :m_ptr(ptr)
    {
    }


    ~Auto_ptr1()
    {
        delete m_ptr;
    }

    T& operator*() const { return *m_ptr; }
    T* operator->() const { return m_ptr; }
};

class Item
{
public:
    Item() { std::cout << "Item acquired\n"; }
    ~Item() { std::cout << "Item destroyed\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    
    Auto_ptr1<Item> item(new Item);
    return 0;
}
```

Интересно понять как происходит выделение памяти в данном случае. Если выполнять программу пошагово ,то сначала выполняется конструктор класса Item , а затем Auto_ptr1.Но где это выделение происходит? Не могу понять в каком порядке происходит выделение, куда передается new Item.

Comment: Ну, вариантов то нет - `Auto_ptr1(T* ptr = nullptr)` - сюда...

Comment: `new Item` создает в куче обьект и возвращает указатель на него. Ну а этот указатель является аргументом конструктора `Auto_ptr1`.

Comment: @EOF ,Harry  а когда вызывается конструктор класса Item? и разве new Item не вернет адрес?

Comment: В `new Item`. Эта часть выделяет память под обьект и сразу создает его там с помощью конструктора по умолчанию и возвращает адрес этого обьекта. Можно написать так: `new Item()`. Это тоже самое.

Comment: @EOF спасибо, а T* ptr = nullptr получит адрес и приравняет к nullputr ?

Comment: Нет. Это значение по умолчанию. `ptr` будет равен `nullptr`, если Вы не передадите в конструктор аргумент. Т.е. как здесь: `Auto_ptr1<Item> item();`

Comment: @EOF а так как я передаю ,то он равен выделенному через конструктор ?

Comment: Да. Но если не передаете, то в таком случае `operator*` попытается разыменовать нулевой указатель. Так что проверка не помешает:)

Comment: @EOF спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
Auto_ptr1<Item> item(new Item);
```

Сначала вызывается `new Item`, который выделяет память для `Item`, вызывает для него конструктор по умолчанию, и возвращает указатель-адрес этого нового `Item`.

Затем создается объект `item` в стеке, которому этот адрес передается в качестве параметра. Вызывается соответствующий конструктор `Auto_ptr1(T* ptr = nullptr)`.